# Is there an absolute accelerated frame of reference?

Tags: reference-frames, rotation, inertial-frames, frame-dragging

I know from special relativity and from a little common sense that there is no absolute inertial frame of reference; that is, physics acts the same no matter what velocity you go at. However, that does not apply to accelerated frames of reference. From my understanding, That would mean that there is an absolute accelerated frame of reference (no acceleration).

Using the same reason, I come to conclude that there is also an absolute angular momentum-based frame of reference; that is to say that there is only one angular momentum-based frame of reference where the laws of physics act the same as in any intertial frame of reference (no angular momentum).

My questions are is there *really* an absolute accelerated frame of reference or a "delta-rotational" frame of reference? Also, [Wikipedia's definition of frame dragging](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging) seems to suggest that large masses can affect these supposedly absolute frames of reference, which seems to imply that they are not absolute. (I'm sorry for using Wikipedia, it's just too useful; it has everything on there, even if occasionally inaccurate. Tell me if the definition on Wikipedia is incorrect/misleading though)

Comment: You started your question framing it in special relativity. The big masses you mentioned in third paragraph fall outside the scope of special relativity.